# Counting and filtering objects in a database with Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm struggling a little to work out how to follow the relation and count fields of objects.

In my Django site, I have a profile model:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
name = models.CharField(_('name'), null=True, blank=True)
about = models.TextField(_('about'), null=True, blank=True)
location = models.CharField(_('location'), null=True, blank=True)
website = models.URLField(_('website'), null=True, blank=True)
```

My understanding is that this is using the username as the foreign key.

I would like to be able to count and display the number of completed profiles my users have filled out, and ones that have a specific "element / field"? (name)* filled out. I tried:

```
Profile.objects.all().count()
```

That gave me the same number of profiles as users, which I am guessing is because the profile model exists for each user, even if it is blank.

I'm unsure how to count profiles that have one of these fields completed in them, and I am also unsure how to count the number of completed "name" fields that have been completed.

I tried:

```
Profile.objects.all().name.count()
```

Django has some good docs on [queryset api](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/), but its currently going a little over my head

- please excuse my use of incorrect terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get them using:

```
Profile.objects.filter(name__isnull=False)
```